# syntax error in xls file?

Tags: php, excel, xls

dont know where the error is in the sourcecode, excel print all the content into 1 line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Styles>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Export">
<Table>
<ROW>
<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">id</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">barcode</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">name</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">price</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">currency</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">store</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">timestamp</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">longitude</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">latitude</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">deal</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">type</Data></CELL><CELL><Data ss:Type="String">devicename</Data></CELL>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">9783827328168</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">123</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">345</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">EUR</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">Lidl</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">1315573726</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">8.666193</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">49.552096</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">dealyes</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">typebrutto</Data></CELL>

<CELL><Data ss:Type="String">m.münzner</Data></CELL>
</ROW>

</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>
```

Comment: There is a backslash in `?\>`

Comment: now excel shows nothing so <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> didnt work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive. Replace "CELL" and "ROW" with "Cell" and "Row". With that and the fix suggested by Pekka, your file loads into Excel fine for me.

Comment: and the warning by excel 2007 about the formatting is this normal?

Comment: excel 2007 => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that. Our proxy server at work bans *all* blogs!

Comment: Okay, I had a look at it on my phone. What file extension are you using for your file? (I was just using XML, which I believe is the right extension for the old Excel XML format.)

Comment: i am using xls for the file so it opens directly with excel  xml isnt attached normally to excel or?  in my php script i wrote:     
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"export.xls\"");

Comment: I think you should probably post another question about the warning specifically; I don't know much about trying to mix file content with the "wrong" file extensions in Excel...